# unable to print custom validator errors in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular

i have implmented one custom validator in angular reactive forms but it is not displaying the error message.
please find code in the below link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yalkcb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve fixed it for you. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewfmt4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts for working state.

I've changed `validateFname` -> `validateFname()` because it is not the validatorFn, but rather a validatorFnFactory

`regForm.controls['fname'].errors.forbiddenName` -> `regForm.controls['fname'].errors?.forbiddenName` in the tamplate. this `?.` operator doesn't evaluate the errors.forbiddenName if errors is null. It makes your console cleaner

`const forbidden = false;` -> `let forbidden = false;` because this is not a constant according to logic

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed and simplified it for you:

On your component.html, add the safe navigation '?' such that the expression will only be evaluated if an error exists (in other words, if `errors` is not null)

```
<tr> 
  <td>
    <span *ngIf="regForm.controls['fname'].errors?.forbiddenName">
      invalid name
    </span>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

and on your component.ts,

```
export function validateFname(control: AbstractControl)  {
  let val = control.value;
  if (val.includes('s')) {
    // return {'forbiddenName': {'value': val}};
    return {'forbiddenName': true}; 
  }
  return null;

}
```

Comment: please take a look of this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70779997/811293