# Recursive Component of Dynamic Angular Forms - ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name:

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, recursive-component, angular-dynamic-forms

I'm creating a project with a `Reactive Form`; based on `Recursive` Component that creates `Dynamic Form` from `JSON` file.

The Sources

##### This is an adaptation from Ionic based on [Creating Dynamic Angular Forms with JSON](https://eliteionic.com/tutorials/creating-dynamic-angular-forms-with-json/)

I Adapted the Recursive version procedures and other changes!

My code is located in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkshmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fjson-form%2Fjson-form.component.html).

I will show a reduced code version of ***json-form.component.html*** file:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div fxLayout="column">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let control of jsonFormData?.controls">
      <div fxFlex="100%">
      
        <selects
          *ngIf="control.type === 'select'"
          [control]="control"
          [visible]="true"
        ></selects>
        
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <button mat-raised-button class="mt-1" color="primary">
    <em class="fa fa-save">Submit</em>
  </button>
</form>
```

As you can see the custom component is **`selects`**.

Now, let's take a look at the `Recursive` code of use of the **`selects`** template. Again I reduce the code of ***select.component.html*** file:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container *ngIf="control?.children">
    <mat-form-field
      *ngIf="control.type === 'select' && control.visible"
      fxFlex="100%"
      hideRequiredMarker
    >
      <mat-label>{{ control.label }}</mat-label>
      <mat-select
        [formControlName]="control.name"
        [placeholder]="control.label"
        (selectionChange)="onSelectChange($event.value)"
      >
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let child of control.children"
          [value]="child.value"
        >
          {{ child.label }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let child of control?.children">
    <div fxFlex="100%">
      <selects *ngIf="child.type === 'select'" [control]="child"></selects>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  
</form>
```

The code of recursion using **`selects`** Component is:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let child of control?.children">
    <div fxFlex="100%">
      <selects *ngIf="child.type === 'select'" [control]="child"></selects>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

An example of error is:

```
ERROR
Error: Cannot find control with name: 'Petitioner (C2 -> P2)'
```

Unfortunately, I can't to find the problem in order to solve it.

**Some clue in order to solve the error?**

**EDIT** I suspect that not all components are shown inmediately, only when the Select is clicked; then the component is not still created.

Comment: Firstly, you need to understand the shape of your root FormGroup value, then generate that FormGroup with nested controls. I don't understand the most nested config: why do you use `siblings` and not `children` and it doesn't have `name` property

Comment: @yurzui `siblings` are not nested Select Component. For this example can be ignored.
Sorry, I didn't catch *Firstly, you need to understand the shape of your root FormGroup value*.
I try to understand, I'm trying to relate the `FormGroup` of `SelectComponent` using `FormGroupDirective` directive.

Comment: You have created only top level FormGroup and always refer to that root FormGroup.

Comment: @yurzui Thank yoy very mych for your time. Now, I need to know how to fix it!.

Comment: Here other example https://dev.to/julianobrasil/writing-nested-recursive-angular-reactive-forms-a-clean-approach-57fk

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the displayed view, all the `FormControl` are there.
But, when a click event is presented. I show the all `FormControl`'s of my `Form` in that istant with the line: `console.log(this.form.value);`

As you can see in the `Green` bottom right rectangle in.
In the last Event. Only appears two controls!!!!, But are shown 7 formControls without button!...
Then my Form (variable `this.form`) need to add those FormControl's.

[image]

**How to do that?**

First, I need to obtain the main `Form` and `FormGroup` (of my parent Component).

In my parent component (`JsonFormComponent`) from the ***json-form.component.ts*** file:

```
export class JsonFormComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() jsonFormData: JsonFormData;

  public myForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({});
  public myFormBuilder: FormBuilder;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myFormBuilder = fb;
  }
```

Now, I have `public` **`myForm`**`: FormGroup...` and `public` **`myFormBuilder`**`: FormBuilder;` for my parent Component!.

The next step, is create local variable in each child-component located in the ***selects.component.ts*** file.

```
export class SelectsComponent implements OnInit {
  public form: FormGroup;
  @Input() formBuilder: FormBuilder;

  constructor(private rootFormGroup: FormGroupDirective) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.rootFormGroup.form;
  }
```

Now, I have `public` **`form`**`: FormGroup...` and `@Input()` **`formBuilder`**`: FormBuilder;` for my child Component!.

The next step, is to pass that objects to my child-components:

The solution in order to pass (or relate) `myForm` (`FormGroup`) comes from this [post](https://blog.profanis.me/blog/reactive-forms-in-parent-child-components).
But, the relation for `myFormBuilder` is done in the ***json-form.component.html*** file.

```
    <selects
      *ngIf="control.type === 'select'"
      [control]="control"
      [visible]="true"
      (addControl)="onAddControl($event)"
      [formBuilder]="myFormBuilder"
    ></selects>
```

Specifically in the line: `[formBuilder]="myFormBuilder"`.

And for the recursion, in the ***selects.component.html*** file

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let child of control?.children">
    <div fxFlex="100%">
      <selects
        *ngIf="child.type === 'select'"
        [control]="child"
        [formBuilder]="formBuilder"
      ></selects>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

Specifically in the line: `[formBuilder]="formBuilder"`.

Now, in my child-component in the file ***selects.component.ts*** I created  this method:

```
  private newControl(control: JsonFormControls) {
    this.form.addControl(
      control.name,
      this.formBuilder.control(control.value, getValidators(control))
    );
    control.visible = true;
  }
```

Lastly: I changed my method, in order to add the `FormControl` that needs to be displayed:

```
  public onSelectChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.control.value = event + '';
    if (this.control.children) {
      this.recursiveConcealer(this.control.children);
      const child = this.control.children.find(
        (child) => child.value === event + ''
      );
      this.newControl(child);
      if (child.siblings) {
        for (let sibling of child.siblings) {
          this.newControl(sibling);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Note specifically the lines: `this.newControl(child);` and `this.newControl(sibling);`.

As you can see in the `Blue` rectangle, the errors are gone.

[image]

**NOTE:** Theres is not the only one solution, here a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547389/how-can-i-pass-the-formgroup-of-a-parent-component-to-its-child-component-using) [How can I pass the FormGroup of a parent component to its child component using the current Form API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38547389/811293) about this subject.